# Async calls and updating variables

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

Consider the following javascript snippet -

```
        var x;
        asyncFunction();
        syncFunction();            

        function syncFunction() {
            console.log(x);
        }


        function asyncFunction() {  
            // any async call or an ajax call
            //setTimeout(function () {
            //    x = 5;                        
            //}, 1000);                
        }
```

The value of the x variable is undefined, since the async function takes some time to execute. Assuming that I don't have the liberty to use Promise/deferreds, pub-sub and also, I should not be changing the order of execution of the async and sync calls in above snippet, how can I achieve the correct value of x being logged correctly? This was an interview question asked to me recently.

Comment: Alter the "asyncFunction" so that it accepts a parameter, and so that the code in the timeout handler treats that parameter as a function and calls it.. Pass the "syncFunction" as that parameter.

Comment: Is this not answered in the [async code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-undefined-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function)?

Comment: WTH was this tagged promise, pub-sub and deferred when that's the things you're *not* supposed to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything meant to be run after an async function should be called from the async function when it's done - a callback.

```
var x;
asyncFunction(syncFunction); // Pass the function as a callback      

function syncFunction() {
    console.log(x);
}


function asyncFunction(callback) {  
    // using your example
    setTimeout(function () {
        x = 5;
        callback();              
    }, 1000);                
}
```

Comment: FYI, you can just do `callback()`.  You don't need `callback.call()`.

Comment: You also should make `x` a parameter, not a global variable.